# Fastest check if line starts with value in list?

Tags: python, performance, filter

I have **thousands of values** (as list but might convert to dictionary or so if that helps) and want to **compare to files with millions of lines**. What I want to do is to **filter lines in files to only the ones starting with values in the list**.

What is the fastest way to do it?

My slow code:

```
  for line in source_file:
    # Go through all IDs
    for id in my_ids:
      if line.startswith(str(id) + "|"):
        #replace comas with semicolons and pipes with comas
        target_file.write(line.replace(",",";").replace("|",","))
```

Comment: I would give regular expressions (the `re` module) a try. You could match the whole file against a regex, or run it line by line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sure the line starts with id + "|", and "|" will not present in id, I think you could play some trick with "|". For example:

```
my_id_strs = map(str, my_ids)
for line in source_file:
    first_part = line.split("|")[0]
    if first_part in my_id_strs:
        target_file.write(line.replace(",",";").replace("|",","))
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Awesome, what took hours before is now done in seconds. I thought splitting the line would make it even slower. Do you think turning list into dictionary and testing the line against dictionary would make it even faster

Comment: @Miro Sure it will. If you will do this operation a lot, it would be better to do some preprocessing like turning into dict as you mentioned.

Comment: I converted the list of strings to dictionary dict_my_ids = dict.fromkeys(my_id_strs) which makes it again a lot faster if used in "if first_part in dict_my_ids:". Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.translate` to do replace. Also you can do a break after you match the id.

```
from string import maketrans

trantab = maketrans(",|", ";,")

ids = ['%d|' % id for id in my_ids]

for line in source_file:
    # Go through all IDs
    for id in ids:
      if line.startswith(id):
        #replace comas with semicolons and pipes with comas
        target_file.write(line.translate(trantab))
        break
```

or

```
from string import maketrans

#replace comas with semicolons and pipes with comas
trantab = maketrans(",|", ";,")
idset = set(my_ids)

for line in source_file:
    try:
        if line[:line.index('|')] in idset:            
            target_file.write(line.translate(trantab))
    except ValueError as ve:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you, in my case replacing is not really that much time consuming because I don't have that many filtered lines but I believe it can also add to the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression. Here is an implementation:

```
import re

def filterlines(prefixes, lines):
    pattern = "|".join([re.escape(p) for p in prefixes])
    regex = re.compile(pattern)
    for line in lines:
        if regex.match(line):
            yield line
```

We build and compile a regular expression first (expensive, but once only), but then the matching is very, very fast.

Test code for the above:

```
with open("/usr/share/dict/words") as words:
    prefixes = [line.strip() for line in words]

lines = [
    "zoo this should match",
    "000 this shouldn't match",
]

print(list(filterlines(prefixes, lines)))
```